# How can i remove this setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm initiating a popup if the user is inactive on the page but want the function that shows the popup to be removed if the user closes the popup, as this is just annoying having this pop open every XX amount of seconds.

This is the function I'm using to call the popup.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var timeoutID;

function setup() {
    this.addEventListener("mousemove", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("mousedown", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("keypress", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("mousewheel", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("touchmove", resetTimer, false);
    this.addEventListener("MSPointerMove", resetTimer, false);

    startTimer();
}
setup();

function startTimer() {
    // wait 20 seconds before calling goInactive
    timeoutID = window.setTimeout(goInactive, 20000);
}

function resetTimer(e) {
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);

    goActive();
}


function goActive() {         
    startTimer();
}

function goInactive() {
    $.magnificPopup.open({
        mainClass: "mfp-fade",
        fixedContentPos: false,
        fixedBgPos: true,
        items: {
            src: "#needtochat"
        },
        removalDelay: 1000, //delay removal by X to allow out-animation
          callbacks: {
            beforeOpen: function() {
               this.st.mainClass = "mfp-3d-unfold";
            },
            close: function() {
                window.clearTimeout(timeoutID); // Thought this may remove the timer function all together?
            }
          },
        type: "inline"}, 0);
}

</script>
```

You'll notice the `function goInactive()` shows the modal window and I have a callback `close:` that I hoped would clear the function.

Comment: It may well be clearing the timer, but you've got a bunch of event listeners that will be recreating it via `resetTimer` -> `goActive` -> `startTimer`

Comment: So the answer would be?

Comment: You must set the flag at start of `goInactive()` function, so you **stop running `goActive()` function inside `resetTimer()`**. What happens now: you clear the timeout, but you set it again in very next moment (using the above event listeners).

Comment: If the pop up is open, there is no reason to show the pop up again so do not set the timer if it is open.

Comment: would you be able to provide an example to an above solution please.

Comment: I see people read my comment, no need for me to post the solution now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `close` callback works as advertised, the timeout will be being cleared.  However, you have attached several event listeners that will immediately recreate the timeout as soon as something happens.  There are two options here.

Option 1: Remove the event listeners, in addition to clearing the timer:

```
function teardown() {
    this.removeEventListener("mousemove", resetTimer);
    this.removeEventListener("mousedown", resetTimer);
    this.removeEventListener("keypress", resetTimer);
    this.removeEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", resetTimer);
    this.removeEventListener("mousewheel", resetTimer);
    this.removeEventListener("touchmove", resetTimer);
    this.removeEventListener("MSPointerMove", resetTimer);
}
```

and within the `close` handler:

```
close: function() {
    teardown();
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
}
```

Option 2: Create a flag and use that to control the creation of the timer:

```
var popupClosed = false;

function resetTimer(e) {
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    if (!popupClosed)
        goActive();
}
```

And set that within the `close` handler:

```
close: function() {
    popupClosed = true;
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
}
```

Comment: Thank you does exactly what it says on the tin!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you can add a variable, for example:

```
var popupBeenClosed = false;
```

change it to true in the "close" callback, and add a check in the resetTimer():

```
function resetTimer(e) {

    if (!popupBeenClosed) {

        window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
        goActive();
    }
```

}